# Nuget VS 2015 Update 2 Doesn't Find All Packages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

We have an internal Nuget server that hosts packages. Up until Update 2 we were able to view all packages hosted on this server, like so:

[image: Pre Update 2 Internal Nuget Packages]

Once upgraded to VS Update 2, we can only see a subset of these packages.

[image: Post Update 2 Internal Nuget Packages]

Using the `find-package` command in Package Manager Console, the results are as follows:

```
PM> find-package

Id                                  Versions                                 Description                                                                                                                                   
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                                   
Core.v35                            {1.2.27}                                 StrongDateTime and Settings                                                                                                                   
Core.v40.Logging                    {1.2.1}                                  Logging library                                                                                                                               
Core.v40.MessageBus                 {1.2.1}                                  Wrapper for message broker access                                                                                                             
Core.v40.NLog.Extensions            {1.2.7}                                  Alternative to Core.v40.Logging, Nlog with message bus target extension                                                                       


PM> find-package ptsr

Id                                  Versions                                 Description                                                                                                                                   
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                                   
PtSR                                {3.1.5}                                  PowerTools Shared References, used to communicate with the PowerTools Platform                                                                


PM> find-package ptvp

Id                                  Versions                                 Description                                                                                                                                   
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                                   
PtVP.v2                             {3.1.5}                                  PowerTools Viewports, used for working with PowerTools data through viewports
```

As you can see, the package `ptsr` and `ptvp` exist, but when executing `find-package`, they are not shown. We are able to `Install-Package` as well, which is a work around.

Does anyone know of a fix for this? Any others experiencing the same thing?

Comment: You probably ought to change the Package source, "Internal Nuget" does not sound much like "TPS Nuget".

Comment: @HansPassant Naming preference of the source is irrelevant. They both point to tpteamfv01:8200/nuget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were running an internal nuget server originally published in 2013, using NuGet.Server.dll version 2.7.40911.225, after installing .net 4.5.2 and updating to the latest internal nuget server 2.10.3 all the packages started showing up in the list. It is unknown what was causing it to not show everything, probably a bug in how it was formatting or escapping the xml feed, browsing the atom feed directly listed all packages in both versions of the nuget server.